# Inserting data into MySQL via PHP, unidentified index and i have defined them?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm trying to set up a webshop for a school project, and i'm having trouble with the order section. I have defined all my variable, to my knowlegde atleast, but it still says "unidentified index".

Here's the form part of the html code (The name's are in Danish, just ignore those)

```
    <div id="bestillingform">
    <table align="center" border="0">
        <form name="bestilling" action="insert.php" method="post">
            <tr id="headline">
                <th colspan="2" align="center"><p>Bestilling</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fornavn: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fornavn" ><br/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Efternavn: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="efternavn" ><br/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Land: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="land" ><br/></td>      
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>By: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="by" ><br/></td>        
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pickup sted: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pickup" ><br/></td>        
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Antal personer: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="antal" ><br/></td>     
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Pakke: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pakke" ><br/></td>     
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kodeord: </td>
                <td><input type="password" name="kodeord" ><br/></td>       
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bestil" ><br/></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here's my php code:

```
    $host="localhost"; 
    $user="root"; 
    $password=""; 
    $database="webshop"; 
    $table="bestilling"; 

    $fnavn = $_POST['fornavn'];
    $enavn = $_POST['efternavn'];
    $land = $_POST['land'];
    $by = $_POST['by'];
    $pickup = $_POST['pickup'];
    $antal = $_POST['antal'];
    $pakke = $_POST['pakke']; 
    $kodeord = $_POST['kodeord'];

    // Forbindelse til server
    mysql_connect($host, $user, $password)or die("Kan ikke forbinde til server");
    mysql_select_db($database)or die("Kan ikke forbinde til databasen");

    $bestil = "INSERT INTO $table(Fornavn, Efternavn, Land, By, Pickup, Antal, Pakke, Kodeord)VALUES('$fnavn', '$navn', '$land', '$by', '$pickup', '$antal', '$pakke', '$kodeord')";

    $result = mysql_query($bestil);

    if ($result){
        echo("<br>Din bestilling er blevet oprettet");
    }else{
        echo(mysql_error());
    } 

    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

I have also tried to post data manually into the table and see if i could retrive them, to check if i had a connection to the database at all - but i didn't have any problems with that, so i'm at a dead end here.

Comment: Which index is it giving you the error on?

Comment: Use `isset()` on all your POST vars.

Comment: your table name it's dynamic but the rows are statics? doesn't make sense

Comment: I used the isset(), and it worked, thanks!
but is get this now:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'By, Pickup, Antal, Pakke, Kodeord)VALUES('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')' at line 1

Comment: Watch out that Little Johnny Tables doesn't fill out your web form.

Answer (score 0):

You use `$navn` in your SQL query, but the variable is actually called `$enavn`.

```
$bestil = "INSERT INTO $table(Fornavn, Efternavn, Land, By, Pickup, Antal, Pakke, Kodeord)VALUES('$fnavn', '$enavn', '$land', '$by', '$pickup', '$antal', '$pakke', '$kodeord')";
```

Change one of these.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword 'by' is a mySQL reserved keyword, and it is one of your field describe in your INSERT statement. You have to surrend it with `by`.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to use **id** in **input tag**, like

```
<input type="text" name="fornavn" id="fornavn" />
```

Then you will get the value in **$_POST['fornavn'']**.

Comment: `id` is not used by forms or `POST`. Only the `name` is required to post the data.